# How did Han Solo meet Chewbacca?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, han-solo, chewbacca

And more precisely, how did Chewbacca come to owe life debt to Han Solo?

I'm also trying to find the first source that says Chewbacca owes a life debt to Solo. I thought it was from the movies, but I cannot find the exact quote.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To answer your second question first (first published mention of life debt):

- The **first mention** of the idea that a debt exists is in Episode V (ESB), when the debt was extended to Leia (Han telling Chewie to now take care of her). This is open to argument, but I personally agree with the concept.
- However, "life debt" as a term **it isn't present in the SW movie trilogy**.
- The first **explicit mention of the term** is in Brian Daley's "[Han Solo Adventures](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Han_Solo_Adventures)" book trilogy - but **NOT in the context of his debt to Han!**

  > "What do
  > we owe Badure?" Han hollered back. "He made a business offer, Chewie. "
  > But he knew better. Wookiees will honor a **Life-Debt** over anything else;
  > he'll never walk away from it, Han thought. Chewbacca growled another
  > angry comment.
- So far I wasn't able to find any mention of life debt as a term in Han/Chewie context that predates A.C. Crispin's [Han Solo trilogy] - see below.

---

*The origin and details of the debt is from the books and mostly comics.*

- Some parts of it were in "The Hutt Gambit" (second book in A.C. Crispin's [Han Solo trilogy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_Trilogy));
- The main info is in [Chewbacca comics](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca_%28comics%29) - specifically [issue #2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Chewbacca_2).
- The **original** mention of the slaver story is in 1978's "[The Wookiee Storybook](http://www.theforce.net/image_popup/image_popup_global.asp?Image=timetales/misc/arcana/wookstory07.jpg)", though that doesn't mention life debt yet.

In short: Chewbacca was a slave under Empire (like many Wookiees) and Han saved his life from another Imperial officer (twice).

Among the reasons for that was that earlier in life another Wookiee (Dewlanna) saved Han's life at the cost of her own.

More details on [SW Wikia:](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca#Meeting_Han_Solo)

> Chewbacca often attempted freeing Wookiees slaves ... On one such endeavor, he became involved in a botched slave transfer between a Trandoshan crew and an Imperial commander Nyklas. Chewbacca orchestrated the escape of close to all of the slaves which consisted mostly of Wookiee children, but in the process had his ship come under fire by Imperial TIE Fighters led by Lieutenant Han Solo. Nyklas was infuriated at the loss of the Wookiee slaves and ordered Solo to kill the Wookiee (who had been rendered unconscious by the firefight). Solo refused, inciting Nyklas's fury, but the commander eventually calmed enough to realize Chewie's value as a slave. .
>
> ... Nyklas worked Chewie unmercifully, taking great pleasure in whipping the demoralized Wookiee. However, Nyklas did not count on any more interventions by Solo, and the young lieutenant saved Chewbacca from being whipped to death. The two escaped from Imperial influence with a small bounty on their heads, and Solo was drummed out of Imperial service.

Comment: And now thanks to Disney, all of this is bound to change in an origin story sometime soon

Comment: Surely Timothy Zahn's Thrawn Trilogy (so early and so good it doesn't actually need a sub-title) predates most everything and the life debt is mentioned in book 1 when Leia is on Kashykk

Comment: @IG_42 - worth a separate answer, IMHO

Comment: Let me get home and cite the chapter, maybe quote

Comment: This answer could use an update now that we have a Disney canon answer.

Comment: There is a separate (albeit currently closed) answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254635/what-life-debt-does-chewbacca-owe-to-han), my suggestion is that we leave both open, tag them with the different levels of canonicity and merge later if it [makes sense to do so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361097/outdated-answers-project-kicking-off-on-stack-overflow)