# Why didn't Han know how to talk with the guard Captain when attempting rescue?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In ANH episode 4 when Han and Luke broke into the detention cell to rescue Lea, they get a call on the com asking what's going on. Han stammers and stutters and asks how the guard is doing in the most conciliatory of tones. When that fails he shoots the console with his blaster. Is there any explanation for this lack of professionalism and ignorance of protocol considering he was retconned to be a former Imperial Officer?

Comment: "considering he was **retconned** to be former Imperial Officer?" Pretty sure that's your answer right there.

Comment: I thought that "conciliatory" fit the situation better.

Comment: @Richard yes that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: Where was Han Solo retconned into a former Imperial Officer?

Comment: I am unaware of any canon star wars with Han as a former Imperial Officer.  While I don't know much, canon is movies and a handful of post-SW4 series...

Comment: "**former** Imperial Officer". Pretty sure *that's* your answer right there

Comment: @TylerH probably *Hutt Gambit*? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36820/47234

Comment: @muru I see, so it's Legends (non) canon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the film's official novelisations, Han was nervous, he panicked and frankly, the guard had already heard too much to believe him. We have three version of the same event and they all stress that he just never had a chance.

> After gesturing for the Wookiee to take up a position where he could cover the elevators, Solo took a deep breath and responded to the unceasing calls from the comlink.
>   “Everything’s under control,” he said into the pickup, sounding reasonably official. “Situation normal.”
>   “It didn’t sound like that,” a voice snapped back in a no-nonsense tone. “What happened?”
>   **“Uh, well, one of the guards experienced a weapon malfunction,” Solo stammered, his temporary officialese lapsing into nervousness.** “No problem now—we’re all fine, thanks. How about you?”
>   “We’re sending a squad up,” the voice announced suddenly.
>   Han could almost smell the suspicion at the other end. What to say? He spoke more eloquently with the business end of a pistol. - <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> “Everything is under control,” he said in his best official, yes-I-belong-here voice. “Situation normal.”
>   “What happened?” a voice crackled through the still-smoking intercom. Han jumped as a spark shot out of it.
>   “Uh…we had a slight weapons malfunction.” **His voice sounded painfully awkward to his own ears, so he could only imagine what the person on the other end was thinking. “But, um, everything’s perfectly all right now. We’re fine. We’re all fine here, now, thank you. How are you?”
>
>   He cringed.** - <sub><sup>[A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>

and

> Over the intercom, a voice asked, “What happened?”
>   “Uh … had a slight weapons malfunction,” Han said, trying to sound official.   “But, uh, everything’s perfectly all right now. We’re fine. We’re all fine here now, thank you. How are you?” **Han winced at the lameness of his own words.**
>   <sub><sup>[A New Hope: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: That cringe/wince isn't just in the novelizations — you can [see it clearly in the film, too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYAbFqkvzQA).

Comment: Been away for a bit and answers get hurried.

Comment: @Morgan - No worries. If you have a quick look at my rep score, you'll see that I've prodded more than my fair share of people to get acceptances sorted today

Comment: I meant buried not hurried. You changed your name? I just don't know who I'm talking to any more...

Comment: @Morgan - I changed my name a few weeks back, shortly before I used the ejector-seat on my Movie:SE account.